# Regex to match more possibilities (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, char, base64

**This regex (for base64):**

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{5}/g
```

**Would match every 5 characters in a string. So if I have:**

```
"19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAw"
```

**the matches are:**

1. 19jZ2
2. uLj5O
3. Xm5+j
4. p6vLz
5. 9PX29
6. /j5+v
7. /aAAw

**How would I write a regex that would result in the following matches?**

1. 19jZ2
2. 9jZ2u
3. jZ2uL
4. Z2uLj
5. 2uLj5
6. uLj5O
7. and so on...

(^Literally every possible 5 consecutive characters in the string)

Comment: You're not really looking for a regex, but a simple loop -> http://jsfiddle.net/Fg9mG/

Comment: That's an excellent idea. The one change I made was "i < str.length - 4" to trim off the extra ones that were less than 5 characters, but put this into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Be aware that your regex will also match comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on adeneo's comment :

```
var result = [],
    s = '19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAw';
while (s.length > 4) {
    result.push(s.substr(0, 5));
    s = s.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
"19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAw".split('').map(function(elm, i, arr) { 
    return arr.slice(i,i+5).join('') }
).slice(0,-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion :

```
function split(s) {
    var allowed = /^[a-z\d/+]{5}/i,
        result = [],
        match;
    while (s.length > 4) {
        match = s.match(allowed);
        match && result.push(match[0]);
        s = s.substr(1); // removes first char
    }
    return result;
}
```

The regex looks for the first five chars for each loop :

```
split('19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAw'); // ['19jZ2', '9jZ2u', ...]
split('19jZ2=uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAw'); // ['19jZ2', 'uLj5O', ...]
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple `([a-zA-Z0-9+\/]{5})` could do it for this specific input

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hE1vF6)

Or `(?:"|\G(?<!^))([a-zA-Z0-9+\/]{5}|[a-zA-Z0-9+\/]+)(?=.*?")` if your string is between quotes

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qA5uT6)

Or `(?:"|\G(?<!^))([a-zA-Z0-9+\/]{5})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+\/]{5})*")` if your string count is exactly a multiple of 5

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yJ3cE2)

Comment: I'm not looking for non-whitespace characters. I'm using all the characters in base64 (as I mentioned in the original post), which are [a-z,A-Z,0-9,+,/].

Comment: @user1868084, then you simply replace `\S` with `[a-zA-Z0-9+\/]`... Answer updated...